# How to use OpenSSL with GCC?

Tags: c++, gcc, linker

I'm trying to use openssl in a gcc program but it isn't working.

```
g++ server.cpp /usr/lib/libssl.a -o server
```

gives an error message, as does anything with the `-l` option. What must I type on the command line to link with openssl? The file `/usr/lib/libssl.a` exists, but nevertheless I still get the linker error `no such function MD5() exists`.

Comment: I don't see the use of -l in te command you posted. And don't post your question in UPPER CASE - shouting is rude.

Comment: Something like `g++ server.cpp -L/usr/lib -lssl -o server` should do the trick.  Post the exact errors that you are getting and someone can help. And I second Neil on the shouting thing ;)

Comment: You're missing `/usr/lib/libcrypto.a`. `libcrypto` provides the crypto used by `libssl`. Add both of these in this exact order because LD is a single pass liker: `/usr/lib/libssl.a /usr/lib/libcrypto.a`.

Answer (score 28):

Without knowing the exact errors you are seeing, it is difficult to provide an exact solution.  Here is my best attempt.

From the information you provided, it sounds as though the linker is failing because it cannot find a reference to the `md5` function in `libssl.a`.  I believe this function is actually in `libcrypto` so you may need to specify this library as well.

`g++ server.cpp -L/usr/lib -lssl -lcrypto -o server`

Answer (score 11):

You or *others* may find this article [developerWorks](https://developer.ibm.com/technologies/linux/tutorials/l-openssl) article helpful.

- [Secure programming with the OpenSSL API](https://developer.ibm.com/technologies/linux/tutorials/l-openssl)

  - https://developer.ibm.com/technologies/linux/tutorials/l-openssl

It describes most things you need to know to get off the ground with OpenSSL and C/C++.  If you find you are following most of the same steps, it might help you see what needs doing.

Good luck.

---

*update*

- [revised link](https://developer.ibm.com/technologies/linux/tutorials/l-openssl):  https://developer.ibm.com/technologies/linux/tutorials/l-openssl

  - Which has been shuffled around
- [original link](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-openssl.html):  http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-openssl.html

  - Which now goes to a digest page including the article.

*Note*: keeping both links because they be used to find new discoveries.

Comment: The three links are the same.

Comment: This should really be a comment. If the link breaks, this answer is worthless. Edit - wait, the link IS broken. Downvote from me.

Answer (score 7):

The location of the library is not fixed. In my case (Ubuntu 18.04), the .a files are located in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/`. So here are the complete steps:

1) [install the library](https://serverfault.com/questions/249340/install-openssl-dev-on-ubuntu-server),

```
sudo apt install libss-dev
```

2) [check the installed files](https://askubuntu.com/questions/32507/how-do-i-get-a-list-of-installed-files-from-a-package),

```
dpkg-query -L libssl-dev
```

3) change the gcc flags `-L(library directory) -l(library name)`, e.g.,

```
gcc XXX.c XXXXX.c -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ -lcrypto -lssl
```

Comment: still does not work for me. and `libcrypto.{so/a}` exists where `-L` is pointing at

Comment: Any error message? Is it still from libcrypto? e.g., If you are using c++, then do not copy & paste my command, use c++ instead.

Comment: nevermind I was using an example program from the openssl website but had not copied all the code... lol

Comment: in the first step should the package be `libssl-dev`?

Comment: @Dipu Yes, it should be. Unfortunately, Stackoverflow doesn't let less than one char edits

Comment: The thing that made it work for me, is putting the file to act upon at the front of the gcc statement. So `gcc ./test.c -L/usr/lib -lssl -lcrypto` works, but `gcc -L/usr/lib -lssl -lcrypto ./test.c` does not

Answer (score 6):

In Eclipse IDE select Your Project property --> c/c++ Build --> Settings gcc c linker(from tools settings)--> add to Library Search Path (-L)

/usr/lib -lssl -lcrypto

Answer (score 0):

On top of the accepted answers, I could not make compile the OpenSSL example for AES-CCM:

https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/demos/evp/aesccm.c

To make it work I needed to add two more things:

- The Dinamic Linking Library : `-ldl`
- The PThread library to use POSIX threading support: `-pthread` (Adding directly the library with  -lpthread is [not recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23250863/difference-between-pthread-and-lpthread-while-compiling) )