# How to include Openssl in my project?

Tags: c, openssl

I have openssl directory for whole openssl code. It has some folder hierarchy. 
I want to use for example RSA algorithm in openssl, how can I include open-sll in my project?

If I just include that directory, program cannot find all files properly. Always error about cannot find some definition or something like that.
Wish I expressed it clearly.
Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[How to use OpenSSL in GCC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894013/how-to-use-openssl-in-gcc)

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
gcc -lssl -lcrypto  ...
```