# undefined reference to md5

Tags: c++, c, encryption, md5

```
#include <openssl/md5.h>
void mMD5(unsigned char * packet, int size) {

    unsigned char* res;

    MD5((unsigned char*)&packet, size, (unsigned char*)&res);

    for(int i=0; i<MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++) {
        printf("%02x", res[i]);
    }
}
```

I get the error: undefined reference to `MD5`

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Answered in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894013/how-to-use-openssl-in-gcc

Comment: doesn't
"unsigned char* res;"
makes buffer overflow ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to link to the matching library. You should have a file called `md5.lib` or `md5.a` or something like that (depending on your OS), and add it to your linker command line (again, depending on your environment).

Comment: In gcc, it's `-lssl -lcrypto`.

Comment: thanks ! it work't! But, do you know how to put set the link options in eclipse?

Comment: I don't really use eclipse, but I imagine you should find it somewhere in the workspace's linker options (or something like that).

Comment: Many thanks my friend! I found how to do it in eclipse to. :)

Comment: Would you know how it is for PostgreSQL? I am having the same problem while writing C code for MD5 in PSQL. But the answer does not help.

Comment: For those who are looking to do this in eclipse, it's Right Click Project -> C/C++ Build Settings -> Tool Settings -> GCC C Linker -> Libraries and then add ssl and crypto in the -l section on the right.