# Difference between -pthread and -lpthread while compiling

Tags: multithreading, gcc, thread-safety, pthreads, compiler-flags

What is the difference between `gcc -pthread` and `gcc -lpthread` which is used while compiling multithreaded programs?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Significance of -pthread flag when compiling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2127797/gcc-significance-of-pthread-flag-when-compiling)

Answer (score 161, accepted):

`-pthread` tells the compiler to link in the pthread library as well as configure the compilation for threads.

For example, the following shows the macros that get defined when the `-pthread` option gets used on the GCC package installed on my Ubuntu machine:

```
$ gcc -pthread -E -dM test.c > dm.pthread.txt
$ gcc          -E -dM test.c > dm.nopthread.txt
$ diff dm.pthread.txt dm.nopthread.txt 
152d151
< #define _REENTRANT 1
208d206
< #define __USE_REENTRANT 1
```

Using the `-lpthread` option only causes the pthread library to be linked - the pre-defined macros don't get defined.

Bottom line: you should use the `-pthread` option.

---

Note: the `-pthread` option is documented as a platform specific option in the GCC docs, so it might not always be available.  However, it is available on platforms that the GCC docs don't explicitly list it for (such as i386 and x86-64) - you should use it when available.

Also note that other similar options have been used by GCC, such as `-pthreads` (listed as a synonym for `-pthread` on Solaris 2) and `-mthread` (for MinGW-specific thread support on i386 and x86-64 Windows). My understanding is that GCC is trying to move to using `-pthread` uniformly going forward.

Comment: Which is weird because it directly contradicts POSIX. POSIX mandates that passing `-lpthread` is enough to get the whole POSIX threading library.

Comment: @FUZxxl Passing `-lpthread` *does* get the whole POSIX threading library.

Comment: @immibis No, what I mean is, POSIX says that linking with `-lpthread` should be enough to get full pthreads support. No other compilation flags should be needed.

Comment: @fuz: POSIX.1-2008 states that `-l pthread` "(...) shall make available all interfaces referenced in <pthread.h> and pthread_kill() and pthread_sigmask() referenced in <signal.h>. **An implementation may search this library in the absence of this option.**" Nothing wrong with GCC.

Comment: @alecov What is wrong with gcc is that compiling with `-lpthread` but not `-pthread` is insufficient to get pthread support, as I already clarified in my previous comment.

Comment: @fuz: The point is that all interfaces referenced in `<pthread.h>` et al _are_ made available, and the pthread library _is_ searched with `-pthread`. This meets the definition of "may search this library in the absence of this option (`-lpthread`)". No further requirement is made by POSIX, nor further "pthread support" defined either.

Comment: @alecov POSIX mandates that pthreads must work if you configure a POSIX environment and link with `-lpthread`.  However, the gcc documentation suggests that this might be insufficient to get pthreads support, which is the point I made through the previous comments.  I don't care at all about what happens if you don't provide `-lpthread` or some random other proprietary options.  Only `-lpthread` is specified by POSIX to guarantee pthreads and that doesn't seems to be sufficient with gcc.

Comment: With clang, and `-lpthread`, we get the message: `clang-7: warning: -lpthread: 'linker' input unused [-Wunused-command-line-argument]`. Perhaps it would be better with `warning: -pthread: 'deprecated flag ignored [-Wunused-command-line-argument]`.

Comment: Regarding `-mthread`, does it use win32threads or does it just makes POSIX threads work for MinGW-w64?

Comment: @HashimAziz There is no native POSIX Pthreads API in native Windows API. [-mthreads documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/x86-Windows-Options.html#index-mthreads-1) says: "_It specifies that MinGW-specific thread support is to be used._" and no further specs or guarantees. You may like to have a look at [WSL2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/compare-versions).

Answer (score 46):

There is an accepted answer, but, IMO, it doesn't provide enough context and insight. Hence this extra answer.

---

`-lpthread` is a solution for a problem that no longer exists (since ~2005).

In the old days there were proprietary implementations of [Pthreads API](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/pthread.h.html) that weren't POSIX-compliant, like [LinuxThreads](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LinuxThreads). POSIX standard merely says that if one wants POSIX-compliant behaviour, then one must link with `-lpthread`, and linking that is required to link a POSIX-compliant implementation of Pthreads API, **should there be ***multiple*** implementations of it**.

There are no multiple implementations of Pthreads API in modern operating systems. And that is why `-lpthread` no longer serves any purpose.

---

Compilers like `gcc` and `clang` (and, probably, all Linux-compatible compilers) **require** using `-pthread` command line option for both compiling and linking POSIX-compliant multi-threaded applications and that is what one must use.

Compiler's documentation is the ultimate authoritive source, any diverging 3rd-party documentation is rather irrelevant.

At compile time, `-pthread` option manifests that Pthread API is requested (there can be multiple threading APIs, e.g. Solaris Threads) and defines platform-specific macros ([`_REENTRANT` on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49999814/412080), `_MT` on Solaris).

At link time, `-pthread` links in required libraries (if any) that implement POSIX-compliant Pthreads API behaviour.

The above makes it clear why `-lpthread` is neither necessary nor sufficient.

---

GNU libc 2.34:

> New applications do not need to link with `-lpthread`, `-ldl`, `-lutil`, `-lanl` anymore.  For backwards compatibility, empty static archives `libpthread.a`, `libdl.a`, `libutil.a`, `libanl.a` are provided, so that the linker options keep working. Applications which have been linked against glibc 2.33 or earlier continue to load the corresponding shared objects (which are now empty).

More info in [Why glibc 2.34 removed `libpthread`](https://developers.redhat.com/articles/2021/12/17/why-glibc-234-removed-libpthread).

Answer (score 18):

`-pthread` Adds support for multithreading with the pthreads library.  This option sets flags for both the preprocessor and linker (`man gcc`).

while

`-lpthread` comes in existence while linking there will be no influence while preprocessing.