# GCC warning with std=c11 arg

Tags: c, gcc, pthreads, c11

Here is a little C source code using pthread_kill() call:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <signal.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        pthread_t th = NULL;

        pthread_kill(th, 0);

        return 0;
}
```

Gcc compilation produces various results depending on -std argument value (see below). I don't understand these different behaviors.
I didn't get interesting informations into man pages except pthread_kill() is POSIX.1-2008 compliant.

Environment: Linux 3.2 64bits. GCC 4.7.2.

### With -std=c11

```
gcc main.c -std=c11 -pthread
```

I get an implicit declaration:

```
main.c:9:2: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘pthread_kill’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
```

### With -std=c99

```
gcc main.c -std=c99 -pthread
```

Same result as -std=c11:

```
main.c:9:2: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘pthread_kill’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
```

### With -std=c90

```
gcc main.c -std=c90 -pthread
```

It simply works without any errors/warnings.

Thank you for your feedbacks.

Comment: did you mean `-lpthread` instead of `-pthread`?

Comment: @SouravGhosh They're exactly the same. Well, actually [-pthread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23250863/difference-between-pthread-and-lpthread-while-compiling) should be preferred.

Comment: Another thing to be aware of is the `-std=gnu99` or e.g. `-std=gnu11` flags that gives you extension to the respective C standard, which includes library features such as posix functions if you are using glibc on linux.

Comment: @nos Actually I'm not interested by GNU extensions and I prefer compile with strict ISO specification (I removed -pedantic* args for the examples).

Comment: @Flow sure, and the reason you're getting a warning here is because the pthread functions are not part of ISO C

Comment: @nos: GNU != POSIX. And extensions to the core language is something different than extensions to libraries.

Comment: @mafso Sure. But regardless of the name being 'gnu', facts are that -std=gnu99 enables the posix interfaces if you are using glibc on linux.  You are absolutely right about the core language being different.

Comment: @nos: My point was, that POSIX doesn't contradict ISO C (it's a strict superset), so using ISO C with POSIX libraries is totally fine. When writing portable code (portable to non-GNU systems, with POSIX support), you don't want to use `-std=gnu99`, but define the feature test macros. (I was a little over-reacting, probably, but there were some answers lately along "if you want to use POSIX extensions, you need `-std=gnu99`", which is wrong; core language extensions and library extensions (and for the latter, GNU, POSIX, BSD extensions) are independent things.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you use a Posix feature, you need to define an appropriate feature test macro. See `man feature_test_macros` or the [Posix standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_02).

If you don't define `_POSIX_C_SOURCE` to an appropriate value (depending on the minimum Posix level you require), then interfaces from that and subsequent Posix standards will not be defined by standard library headers.

If you need Posix.1-2008, for example, you need to do this:

```
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <signal.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        pthread_t th = NULL;

        pthread_kill(th, 0);

        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that was the solution. However, how am I supposed to know this function is a Posix feature? pthread_create() is also Posix (1.2001) but I didn't ever specify it.
According to your documentation, I didn't see "feature_test_macros" mention inside pthread_kill() man page.

Comment: @Flow - I think the point is, pthreads are *not* part of ISO C. "how am I supposed to know this function is a Posix feature?" - Pthreads is short for 'POSIX threads'. It is a bit strange that including the header doesn't expose the functionality, but pthreads still affect compiler options / linking in some cases.

Comment: @Flow: Most manpages have a section on feature test macros; if pthread_create is missing one in your system, I would say that is a documentation bug. However, you can derive the value from the `CONFORMING TO` line, using the chart in the posix standard whose link is in the answer. I just use 200809L all the time (I put `-D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200809L` in my C flags in my Makefile) but it is probably "better" to be precise.