# problems faced during multithreading in cortex m3 microsemi softconsole platform

Tags: multithreading, cortex-m

right now am working on cortexm3 processor evaluation kit in microsemi softconsole platform.In that am trying multithread programming.If i run my multithreading code in soft console workspace. it will show the following  errors
 1)make:***[hello_world.o]error 1 
 2)semaphore.h no such file or dictionary
 Even though if i included semaphore.h it is showing no such file is included..if any one know solutions for the above 2 queries let me know

thank you
sachith

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please consider formatting your question http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting for readability

Comment: So where is that header file actually located, and what include paths are you passing to the compiler?

Comment: Are you using RTOS?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run a multithreaded application just add a LDFLAG
 -lpthread    during compilation

you can refer to following page for the usage

[Difference between -pthread and -lpthread while compiling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23250863/difference-between-pthread-and-lpthread-while-compiling)

EDIT:
for e.g.--->
arm-uclinuxeabi-gcc -CFLAGS  filename.c -o fileoutput -L -lpthread