# -pthread, -lpthread and minimal dynamic linktime dependencies

Tags: c, linux, gcc, pthreads, glibc

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23250863/difference-between-pthread-and-lpthread-while-compiling) suggest `-pthread` is preferable to `-lpthread` because predefined macros.

Empirically, `-pthread` gives me only one extra macro: `#define _REENTRANT 1`
and it also appears to force `libpthread.so.0` as a dynamic linktime dependency.

When I compile with `-lpthread`, that dependency is only added if I actually call any of the `pthread` functions.

This is preferably to me, because then I wouldn't have to treat multithreaded programs differently in my build scripts.

So my question is, what else is there to `-pthread` vs `-lpthread` and is it possible to use use `-pthread` without forcing said dynamic linktime dependency?

Demonstration:

```
$ echo 'int main(){ return 0; }' | c gcc -include pthread.h -x c - -lpthread && ldd a.out | grep pthread
$ echo 'int main(){  return pthread_self(); }' | c gcc -include pthread.h -x c - -lpthread && ldd a.out | grep pthread
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x0000003000c00000)
$ echo 'int main(){ return 0; }' | c gcc -include pthread.h -x c - -pthread && ldd a.out | grep pthread
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x0000003000c00000)
```

Comment: Why would you use `-pthread` (or `-lpthread`) for a program that doesn't actually use pthreads?  And given, then, that your program in fact does use pthreads, why is there an issue?

Comment: To my understanding the only reason you'd want this is to have a *universal build command*, which is never a good idea. I mean it's either your executable is multi threaded or not. You should not have to rely on gcc's smart linkage.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Generic project builds.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The idea that you should use GCC's special option `-pthread` instead of `-lpthread` is outdated by probably some decade and a half (with respect to glibc, that is). In modern glibc, the switch to threading is entirely dynamic, based on whether the pthreads library is linked or not. Nothing in the glibc headers changes its behavior based on whether `_REENTRANT` is defined.

As an example of the dynamic switching, consider `FILE *` streams. Certain operations on streams are locking, like `putc`. Whether you're compiling a single-threaded program or not, it calls the same `putc` function; it is not re-routed by the preprocessor to a "pthread-aware" `putc`. What happens is that do-nothing stub functions are used to go through the motions of locking and unlocking. These functions get overridden to real ones when the threading library is linked in.

---

---

I just did a cursory `grep` through the include file tree of a glibc installation. In `features.h`, `_REENTRANT` causes `__USE_REENTRANT` to be defined. In turn, exactly one thing seems to depend on whether `__USE_REENTRANT` is present, but has a parallel condition which also enables it. Namely, in `<unistd.h>` there is this:

```
#if defined __USE_REENTRANT || defined __USE_POSIX199506
/* Return at most NAME_LEN characters of the login name of the user in NAME.
   If it cannot be determined or some other error occurred, return the error
   code.  Otherwise return 0.

   This function is a possible cancellation point and therefore not
   marked with __THROW.  */
extern int getlogin_r (char *__name, size_t __name_len) __nonnull ((1));
#endif
```

This looks dubious and is obsolete; I can't find it in the master branch of the glibc git repo.

And, oh look, **just mere days ago** (December 6) a commit was made on this topic:

https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=commit;h=c03073774f915fe7841c2b551fe304544143470f

```
Make _REENTRANT and _THREAD_SAFE aliases for _POSIX_C_SOURCE=199506L.

For many years, the only effect of these macros has been to make
unistd.h declare getlogin_r.  _POSIX_C_SOURCE >= 199506L also causes
this function to be declared.  However, people who don't carefully
read all the headers might be confused into thinking they need to
define _REENTRANT for any threaded code (as was indeed the case a long
time ago).
```

Among the changes:

```
--- a/posix/unistd.h
+++ b/posix/unistd.h
@@ -849,7 +849,7 @@ extern int tcsetpgrp (int __fd, __pid_t __pgrp_id) __THROW;
    This function is a possible cancellation point and therefore not
    marked with __THROW.  */
 extern char *getlogin (void);
-#if defined __USE_REENTRANT || defined __USE_POSIX199506
+#ifdef __USE_POSIX199506
 /* Return at most NAME_LEN characters of the login name of the user in NAME.
    If it cannot be determined or some other error occurred, return the error
    code.  Otherwise return 0.
```

**See?** :)

Comment: "The idea that you should use GCC's special option -pthread instead of -lpthread is outdated by probably some decade and a half (with respect to glibc, that is)." -- this is correct, but *only* applies to glibc. If you build for other platforms, you could easily get in trouble by *not* using `-pthread`, so it's preferable to use `-pthread` instead of `-lpthread`, because the former is *always* correct, and the latter is not necessarily.

Answer (score 5):

The other answer explains that `-pthread` (at both compile and link time) is functionally equivalent to `-lpthread` (at link time only) **when the C library is the GNU C library**.  But that's not the only C library in the world.

I do not know whether any of the *current* generation of POSIX-compliant operating systems require anything more than `-lpthread` at link time for a threaded application, but if you use `-pthread` at both compile and link time, you will at least make life easier for people trying to keep old iron running.

Having said that, old iron will also be happier if you *don't* use `-pthread` (or `-lpthread`) on programs that don't need to use threads.  "Generic project builds" are not a good idea.

The problem of shared libraries getting pulled in when they don't need to be is best solved by `-Wl,--as-needed` (with GNU-compatible linkers).  This is only not on by default for backward compatibility's sake.