# why do we need "-pthread" flag to compile a c file

Tags: c, multithreading, gcc

I try to compile a c file which was include threads. but i tried to compile normal way like this

> gcc -o thread thread.c -Wall

But it gives an error. but I tried to compile like this way

> gcc -pthread -o thread thread.c -Wall

It worked. what is the reason of this and -pthread flag what will do?
my C code below

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void *thread_function(void *arg)
{
    int a;
    for(a=0;a<10; a++)
    {
    printf("Thread says hi!\n");
    sleep(2);
    }
    return NULL;
}

int main(void)
{
    pthread_t mythread;
    if ( pthread_create( &mythread, NULL, thread_function, NULL) )
    {
        printf("error creating thread.");
        abort();
    }
    if ( pthread_join ( mythread, NULL ) )
    {
    printf("error joining thread.");
    abort();
    }
    printf("Main thread says hi!\n");
    exit(0);
}
```

Comment: You should look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23250863/difference-between-pthread-and-lpthread-while-compiling. Essentially, you need to tell the compiler to link in pthread library

Comment: What's particularily unclear about the gcc documentation?

Comment: Read this for reference [https://randu.org/tutorials/threads/](https://randu.org/tutorials/threads/)

Comment: Actually, both -pthread and -lpthread are platform-dependent. Some standard C libraries, e.g., Android Bionic, provide internal implementations of `pthread_create()`, etc. Stop me if I'm not helping ;)

Comment: I didn't see those links. there are lot of link about this error. I checked some of them I did't get answer. above link gives right answer thanks for helping me

Answer (score 1):

According to [gcc](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.4.6/gcc/SPARC-Options.html) reference:

> **-pthreads**
>
> Add support for multithreading using the POSIX threads library. This
>   option **sets flags for both the preprocessor and linker**. This option
>   does not affect the thread safety of object code produced by the
>   compiler or that of libraries supplied with it.

Answer (score -2):

It compiles without `-pthread` just fine

```
gcc -c thr.c
```

but it won't link. To make it link, you need -lpthread or -pthread.

```
gcc thr.c -pthread
```

Using only the linking flag (-lpthread) should be sufficient (see [-pthread, -lpthread and minimal dynamic linktime dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41267121/1084774) ).