# why -pthread is required as an argument for compiling pthread c programs

Tags: c, gcc, pthreads

Why do when we use `pthread.h` library function in a c program, to compile it we have to write
`gcc program.c -pthread` Why doesn't `gcc program.c` works. Although the simple reason could be 
that it includes the pthread library when we specify the -pthread tag. But then we don't pass 
any such argument when we include other header files. Is it because that pthread is an 
 `external library` than what's available from within C?

Comment: Does this answer your quesiton? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2127797/significance-of-pthread-flag-when-compiling

Comment: Another good dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41267121/pthread-lpthread-and-minimal-dynamic-linktime-dependencies

Answer (score 4):

The functions in libraries such as `stdlib.h` and `stdio.h` have implementations in libc.so, which is linked into your executable by default (as if `-lc` were specified).

Libraries such as `math.h` and `pthread.h` are not included in libc.so and hence have to be linked separately. This can be done by passing the `-lm` and `-lpthread` arguments respectively.

`gcc program.c` will actually compile perfectly but the linker will not find the required function definitions used and will hence throw an error.

Comment: whats the different between compiling with -pthread argument and -lpthread argument?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23250863/difference-between-pthread-and-lpthread-while-compiling