# cross compilation executable can't resolve symbol pthread_create

Tags: c, mips, cross-compiling

I compile the latest buildroot, and use the output host `mipsel-linux-gcc` to compile my c program. I have tested the hello world program and it run fine on MIPS machine(actually a router flashed with padavan). Then I compiled my program and it run good util it calls `pthread_create`, showing that it can't resolve symbol `pthread_create`.

I thought maybe it's because the router doesn't have libpthread.so, so I checked:

```
[RT-AC54U /home/root]# find / -name "*pthread*"
/lib/libpthread-0.9.33.2.so
/lib/libpthread.so.0
```

it turned out the libpthread so file does exist.

Then I suspected maybe it's cause by the cross compilation setting. So I checked the link library by adding `-L. -Wl,--verbose` options (learned from other SO post) and find:

```
attempt to open buildroot/output/host/usr/mipsel-buildroot-linux-uclibc/sysroot/usr/
lib/libpthread.a succeeded
```

when linking, linker only finds the `libpthread.a`, all `libpthread.so` searching fail. Seeing this I checked using `find . -name "*pthread.so"` in the buildroot directory and find nothing.

If linker only find the pthread static library then why it doesn't complaint? I skimmed through the `make menuconfig` and have not seen any option concerning  pthread library.

The readelf output is:

```
readelf -d ./myprogram |grep NEEDED
0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libc.so.0]
```

We could see that the program doesn't include the need for `libpthread`! Compared with the same program compiled by native(x64) gcc:

```
readelf -d ./myprogram |grep NEEDED
0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libpthread.so.0]
0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libc.so.6]
```

My best guess now is that `mipsel-linux-gcc` can't find `libpthread.so` ,thus didn't add information about libpthread to executable. Though strangely it didn't complain at all.

Could anyone tell me what's wrong? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `-lpthread` in compilation command

e.g.:

```
gcc <source file>.c -o <object file name> -lpthread
```

gcc is the compiler command.

`-lpthread` is option to execute `pthread.h` library file.

Comment: ==，well, I forget to mention I did use `-pthread` in gcc command. Thank you for your advise

Comment: Maybe you could have a look at this SO post:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23250863/difference-between-pthread-and-lpthread-while-compiling  Using the -lpthread option only causes the pthread library to be linked - the pre-defined macros don't get defined.

Comment: By the way, I confirm that switch to `-lpthread` doesn't make a difference, still see no pthread NEEDED part in elf file  I will working on find a MIPS libpthread.so to place in buildroot and see what happened