# Errors while compiling openssl project example

Tags: boost, makefile, openssl, boost-beast

I'm trying to build example [advanced-flex](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/libs/beast/example/advanced/server-flex/advanced_server_flex.cpp) from boost-beast git example. I installed both boost and openssl from sources, so [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23250863/difference-between-pthread-and-lpthread-while-compiling) didn't help me. I've basic understanding of building projects, my attempt is (-I... to fix openssl fatal error: openssl/conf.h: No such file or directory):

```
g++ -o app main.cpp -I/usr/local/ssl/include
```

I get enormous list of errors ending with:

```
...
main.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost4asio3ssl6detail6engine8do_writeEPvm[_ZN5boost4asio3ssl6detail6engine8do_writeEPvm]+0x3d): undefined reference to `SSL_write'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Which leads me to post from stackoverflow I referenced earlier, I've tried then:

```
g++ -pthread -o qm_app main.cpp -I/usr/local/ssl/include -I/usr/local/ssl/lib -lssl -lcrypto

/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lssl
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcrypto
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Folder usr/local/ssl/lib content:

```
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root    4096 мая  7 14:27 .
drwxr-xr-x 9 root root    4096 мая  7 14:27 ..
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root    4096 мая  7 14:27 engines-1.1
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 5722096 мая  7 14:27 libcrypto.a
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      16 мая  7 14:27 libcrypto.so -> libcrypto.so.1.1
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 3428768 мая  7 14:27 libcrypto.so.1.1
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1043808 мая  7 14:27 libssl.a
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      13 мая  7 14:27 libssl.so -> libssl.so.1.1
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  692840 мая  7 14:27 libssl.so.1.1
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root    4096 мая  7 14:27 pkgconfig
```

Comment: As option may have importance, you could try `g++ -pthread -I/usr/local/ssl/include -L/usr/local/ssl/lib -lssl -lcrypto -o qm_app main.cpp`. Also, you should use option `-L` instead of `-I` when you specify a directory where to look for librairies

Comment: @Zelnes Thanks, but right order (at least for me):   g++ -pthread -o qm_app main.cpp -I/usr/local/ssl/include -L/usr/local/ssl/lib -lssl -lcrypto

Comment: What happens when you build the example using bjam?