# g++ compiling error message: /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lssl

Tags: c++, database, ubuntu, g++, dolphindb

I followed the [tutorial](https://github.com/dolphindb/api-cplusplus) to connect to DolphinDB server with C++ and encounted this error message when compiling **main.cpp**:

```
$ g++ main.cpp -std=c++11 -DLINUX -DLOGGING_LEVEL_2 -O2 -I../include -lDolphinDBAPI -lssl -lpthread -luuid -L../bin -Wl,-rpath ../bin/ -o main
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lssl
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Note that my g++ version is above v6.2:

```
$ g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04) 7.4.0
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

How to solve this error?

Comment: You probably need to install libssl.

Comment: As an aside, take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23251828/1171191).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to link against OpenSSL, you need to install the development package for OpenSSL, like this:

```
apt install libssl-dev
```

It may also be possible to drop the `-lssl` from the linker command line. (If there was a project dependency on OpenSSL, the build would not have gotten this far because the OpenSSL header files are missing, too.)