# Why do you need '-lpthread'?

Tags: c, gcc, compilation, pthreads

So my questions is: Why do you need '-lpthread' at the end of a compiling command?

Why does this command work:

```
gcc -o name name.c -lpthread
```

but this won't:

```
gcc -o name name.c
```

I am using the pthread.h library in my c code.
I already looked online for some answers but didn't really find anything that answered it understandably

Comment: Presumably because pthreads isn't standard C. All libs that aren't standard C are linked with `-lsomething`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23250863/difference-between-pthread-and-lpthread-while-compiling

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`pthread.h` is not a library **it is just a header file** which gives you declaration (not the actual body of function) of functions which you will be using for multi-threading.

using `-libpthread` or `-lpthread` while compiling actually links the GCC library `pthread` with your code. Hence the compiler flag, `-libLIBRARY_NAME` or `-lLIBRARY_NAME` is essential.

If you don't include the flags `-l` or `-lib` with `LIBRARY_NAME` you won't be able to use the external libraries.

In this case, say if you are using functions `pthread_create` and `pthread_join`, so you'll get an error saying:

```
undefined reference to `pthread_create'

undefined reference to `pthread_join'
```

Comment: a header file (which is informally called as .h file) only contains declaration of functions. where as a library which can be static library (.a file) or dynamic library (.dll file on windows & .so file on linux distributions) consist of binary version of code (it's more than that) but that's the most simplest explanation which I can find out.

for more information refer.
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-header-file-library/

Answer (score 5):

The `-l` options tells the linker to link in the specified external library, in this case the pthread library.

Including pthread.h allows you to use the functions in the pthread library in you code.  However, unlike the functions declared in places like studio.h or stdlib.h, the actual code for the functions in pthread.h are not linked in by default.

So if you use functions from this library and fail to use `-lpthread`, the linking phase will fail because it will be unable to find functions in the library such as `pthread_create`, among others.