# How is using -pthread not violation ODR rules?

Tags: c++, c, pthreads, one-definition-rule

I've recently come about a Python extension/package build via CFFI which uses `pthread_atfork` (and a pthread mutex) but does not link against pthread, i.e. specifies neither `-pthread` nor `-lpthread` and hence fails on systems which have a static part which is linked in by a libpthread link script (as opposed to a purely shared library) due to missing symbols.

When thinking about the correct fix I stumbled over the [Difference between -pthread and -lpthread while compiling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23250863/difference-between-pthread-and-lpthread-while-compiling). So using `-pthread` on compile and link step does not only place `-lpthread` at the correct position (crucial in the above setup) but also defines preprocessor symbols which change definitions of functions.

An example of a (third-party) function is `boost::datetime::c_time::localtime(...)` which calls either `localtime_r` or `std::localtime`.

Isn't that a (very likely) source for ODR violations? So e.g. compiling a simple static library not using threads at all without `-pthread` and linking that into a binary which does use threads and hence is using `-pthread` will lead to different definitions of such a function and be UB(/IB?)?

However from my `/usr/include/features.h` I see

```
   _REENTRANT, _THREAD_SAFE
      Obsolete; equivalent to _POSIX_C_SOURCE=199506L.
```

So questions:

1. Are/were there ODR violations due to `-pthread` and if so why (was
   it not avoided/on purpose/an oversight)?
2. Are those definitions no longer relevant? So `-pthread` is now equivalent to `-lpthread` (save the placement)?
3. What should one use to build a CFFI extension for Python? Using `-pthread` is difficult due to compiler dependent naming (`-pthread, -pthreads, -mthreads`, ...)

Answer (score 4):

On Linux, the flag `-pthread` as opposed to `-lpthread` indeed only additionally passes the flag `-D_REENTRANT` to the gcc options, which is obsolete nowadays.

See also this comment in `features.h`:

```
/* Some C libraries once required _REENTRANT and/or _THREAD_SAFE to be
   defined in all multithreaded code.  GNU libc has not required this
   for many years.  We now treat them as compatibility synonyms for
   _POSIX_C_SOURCE=199506L, which is the earliest level of POSIX with
   comprehensive support for multithreaded code.  Using them never
   lowers the selected level of POSIX conformance, only raises it.  */
```

However, there might still be C standard library implementations, which rely on `_REENTRANT` to be defined when compiling multithreaded code. For libc (and probably in most other environments) however, you can safely use `-lpthread` for compiling.

Comment: Alright thanks. And for those C standard library implementations does it indeed lead to ODR violations?