# 64-bit release build gives me a GLIBC relocation error

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, glibc

I have been getting the error below when compiling and running my application for 64-bit release (release just has optimisation level `-O2` on that debug does not).

The 32-bit debug version runs ok. The 64-bit debug version crashes (this is what I am trying to solve), but the 64-bit release version gives me this error. I am guessing that they are related - but not 100% sure about that.

Here is the error:

```
./tester_x64Linux: relocation error: /home/user/development/lib/libcontroller_library_x64Linux.so.0: symbol nanosleep version GLIBC_2.2.5 not defined in file libpthread.so.0 with link time reference
```

I am running on ubuntu 18:04 with c++17 standard and I have tested this with gccv7 and gccv8 both with the same results.

Note: that I compile the library with the same make tools (and flags etc) as I do my binary

so `/home/user/development/lib/libcontroller_library_x64Linux.so.0` is compiled first and then `tester_x64Linux` is compiled.

After tsrying to read about what the GLIBC error is trying to tell me, I find I am hitting lots of false positives (in google searches) because there seems to be some oldes issues like GLIBC `verno.h` file not included in older GBLIC versions (2.0 IIRC).
I do have some threads running and I used functions like `std::this_thread::sleepfor(...)` which I believe use `nanosleep` under the hood.

So now I am not quite sure how to progress. Usually this would (IMO) imply some library that I have linked needs to be recompiled with newer GLIBC - but in this case its a library that I am compiling and have re-compiled every time I compile my binary (if I do a clean) - so it should be compiled to the same level as my executable.

Maybe my `libpthread.so.0` is too old? - but then I would be very confused as I have used this on many other projects (with the same libraries) with no problems (thus far).

**update:** just tested this against 2 other applications that are built in the exact same way with the same libraries - just different app code, but that have threads - and they are both ok (just confused now).

Any pointers would be appreciated

**update 2**

My specific flags are (not including warning and include paths - which there are lots)

- Compiler: `-m64 -O2 -g  -std=c++17`
- linker: `-m64 -O2 -g -rdynamic -lstdc++ -lpthread -lrt -lsystemd -ldl`

the main difference with x86 build is that I use flag `-m32` instead.

**update 3**

nm output for nanosleep in libc and libpthread:

```
[user] ~$ nm -CD --with-symbol-versions /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 | grep nanosleep
0000000000130dd0 T __clock_nanosleep@@GLIBC_PRIVATE
0000000000130dd0 W clock_nanosleep@@GLIBC_2.17
00000000000e4760 W nanosleep@@GLIBC_2.2.5
00000000000e4760 T __nanosleep@@GLIBC_2.2.6
[user] ~$ nm -CD --with-symbol-versions /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 | grep nanosleep
0000000000011d10 W nanosleep@@GLIBC_2.2.5
0000000000011d10 T __nanosleep@@GLIBC_2.2.6
```

**update 4**

Precise compiler and linker commands for controller lib:

Note: there are many files, so I will just put in one for as an example - and I will redact some of the include paths to hide project specific details:

Compile

```
src/bsp_api.cpp
g++ -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -Wconversion -Wsign-conversion -Wunreachable-code -Wlogical-op -Wshadow -Wmissing-include-dirs -Wparentheses -Werror -Wno-psabi -Wno-error=deprecated-declarations -Wuseless-cast -Wduplicated-cond -Wnull-dereference -Iinc -Iinc/api -m64 -g -fPIC -std=c++17  -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage -DRTI_UNIX -DPLANTUML_DDS_TRACE -DNO_MAIN -c src/bsp_api.cpp -o obj/x64Linux_debug/gcov/src/bsp_api.o
```

Link

```
gcc -m64 -g -shared -Wl,-soname,libcontroller_library_x64Linuxd.so.0 -lgcov --coverage -o lib/libcontroller_library_x64Linuxd.so.0.2 OBJS_HERE -lstdc++ -lpthread -lrt -lsystemd
```

Note: this lib does not have `rdynamic` - I only  use that for executables and not libraries. Note also `-lpthread` as pointed out, I will start to update this to `-pthread` at a later time.

LDD

```
[user] controller_library$ ldd lib/libcontroller_library_x64Linuxd.so.0
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffcc7d5a000)
        libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007fa2afe25000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fa2afc06000)
        libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007fa2af9ee000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fa2af5fd000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007fa2af25f000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fa2b0a3a000)
```

**update 5**

Searched for all libpthreads on my system. Most of these are cross compiler varients - which are not relevant (and would completely fail at link time due to different arch. The only one I can see that looks "rogue-ish" is `./usr/libx32/libpthread.so` - but that is 32bit. There is only 1 64-bit libpthread on my whole system and its the expected one../

```
[user] /$ find -name "libpthread.so" 2> /dev/null
./usr/lib32/libpthread.so
./usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so
./usr/libx32/libpthread.so
./opt/trl-imx-scs/5.4-zeus/sysroots/aarch64-poky-linux/usr/lib/libpthread.so
./opt/trl-imx-scs/4.14-sumo/sysroots/aarch64-poky-linux/usr/lib/libpthread.so
./opt/trl-imx-6GTcvr/4.1.15-1.2.0/sysroots/cortexa9hf-vfp-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/usr/lib/libpthread.so
./opt/fsl-imx-x11/4.1.15-1.1.1/sysroots/cortexa9hf-vfp-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/usr/lib/libpthread.so
./opt/fsl-imx-x11/4.9.51-mx8-beta/sysroots/aarch64-poky-linux/usr/lib/libpthread.so
./opt/trl-imx-6GTcvr-PECM/5.4-zeus/sysroots/cortexa9t2hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/usr/lib/libpthread.so
./opt/trl-imx-6GTcvr-PECM/4.14-sumo/sysroots/cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/usr/lib/libpthread.so
./opt/trl-ccs-kontron/sdk_v0.1.0/usr/lib/libpthread.so
```

Comment: When faced with an issue like this I usually just start deleting stuff until it goes away, then add things back until it manifests again. With things like `git bisect` you can actually do it more systematically.

Comment: From the error message it looks like the version of libpthread.so found by the loader is *not* the one that libcontroller_library_x64Linux.so.0 was originally built against (I think).  Hence the symbol version mismatch.

Comment: @TedLyngmo my specific flags are (not including warning and include paths - which there are lots) Compiler: `-m64 -O2 -g  -std=c++17`, linker: `-m64 -O2 -g -rdynamic -lstdc++ -lpthread -lrt -lsystemd -ldl` - the mainn difference with x86 build is that I use flag `-m32` instead

Comment: @code_fodder Put the line in the question. Don't use `-lpthread` btw. Use [`-pthread`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23250863/difference-between-pthread-and-lpthread-while-compiling).

Comment: A message like "version GLIBC_2.2.5 not defined" means you have a binary built on a different (newer) OS with newer glibc, or with a non-default toolchain. The toolchain is backwards-compatible, but not forwards-compatible.

Comment: @G.M. thanks for that - but I am not quite sure how that is possible? - the controller library (which is my code) does include other 3rd party libs, but I would have thought if they where incorrect the error would compain about those libs...

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. This is what I can't understand. I have ubuntu 18:04 64-bit and also multilib (for x86 compiling). The default is gcc7, I have also installed gcc8. I have tried building with gcc7 and gcc8 and both give me the same issue - but there is nothing non-standard on the VM... any thoughts?

Comment: Nitpick: `-rdynamic` is a compiler flag. `-export-dynamic` is the corresponding linker flag.

Comment: @TedLyngmo - happy with nit-picking :) ... seemed to work though - I guess gcc figured out what I was trying to do, will update.

Comment: :-) `ld: unrecognised option: -rdynamic` is what I get.

Comment: @TedLyngmo how odd.... I dont get that - maybe I have newer (or older) gcc (tested with both gcc 8.4 and 7.5). But it seems happy with -export-dynamic ... i'll look into that once I get over my current issue!

Comment: do this: `nm -CD --with-symbol-version /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 | grep nanosleep` what do you see? Same for `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0`.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. I have added that to the end of my question - they appear to be the same - is that what you would expect?

Comment: What is the exact command, with every single option, that you are using to build `libcontroller_library_x64Linux.so.0`? What is the output of `ldd libcontroller_library_x64Linux.so.0`?

Comment: @code_fodder Did you actually type `ld -rdynamic` to see if it accepts that option?

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. I have added the compile and link lines (with some sensible omissions like many inc paths, and the list of my objects from the linker). Also the LDD output - nothing special in there. All the extra (third party libs) are included when I do the executable link - there a lots more output from LDD, but if its complaining about controller lib, then I am not sure if that is relevant

Comment: Also I am using gcc to link - so I just read that -rdynamic does : `-rdynamic
Pass the flag -export-dynamic to the ELF linker` from: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html#index-rdynamic

Comment: @code_fodder Ok, that's what I was aiming at when I said "_`-rdynamic` is a compiler flag. `-export-dynamic` is the corresponding linker flag_". :-) Ok, that's sorted out then.

Comment: `-lstdc++` Never do this. Use `g++` as your linker instead. (This may or may not be related to your problem) Also please search for a library named libpthread.so in your entire project, you may have some stray copy.

Answer (score 0):

A guess: you have a bogus `libpthread.so.0` *somewhere* on your system, and that library gets used *in preference of* the standard `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0`.

You did `ldd lib/libcontroller_library_x64Linuxd.so.0`, but that tells you *nothing*. You need to do `ldd tester_x64Linux` instead.

Better sill, do this:

```
LD_DEBUG=libs,files ./tester_x64Linux
```

That will tell you which `libpthread.so.0` is *actually* used at runtime.

Comment: Ok, thanks for this - I will try this on Monday when I get back in. I did do a search for libpthread - I have the 64 and 32 bit varient, but I did not see much else, I will re-check then. I support I could try a fresh VM and re-test...

Comment: hmm... so its just using the standard one from here: `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0`. Also I have a lot of other programs that run find with the same setup (different top level app), so I am just surprised it is only this one exe that is complaining

Comment: @code_fodder I have a few other guesses about what may be wrong. Can you show output from `ldd tester_x64Linux`? Does the test `dlopen("libcontroller_library_x64Linuxd.so.0", ...)` or does it link _directly_? Does a trivial `int main() { return 0; }` linked directly against `libcontroller_library_x64Linuxd` with `-Wl,--no-as-needed` flag exhibit the same problem?