# g++10, C++20, boost 1.75.0 :: error: 'awaitable' has not been declared in 'boost::asio'

Tags: c++, boost, coroutine, asio, c++-coroutine

I tried to compile the example: `echo_server_with_as_single_default.cpp` from [boost](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp17/coroutines_ts/echo_server_with_as_single_default.cpp) examples on an:

- ubuntu 18.04
- boost 1.75.0
- g++ 10.1.0

Using the following commands to compile&link (I know it's not optimal, I reused the makefile from another project I am working on):

```
g++ -MT bin/.o/src/main.o -MD -MP -MF bin/.d/src/main.d -std=c++20 -Isrc -Ilib/ -g -Wfatal-errors -c -o bin/.o/src/main.o src/main.cpp
g++ -o bin/server bin/.o/src/main.o  -lpthread -lrt -lboost_system -lboost_thread -lboost_chrono -lboost_context -lboost_coroutine -DBOOST_COROUTINES_NO_DEPRECATION_WARNING
```

And I get the following error:

I tried diferrent combinations but there is something I am missing. Any help?

```
error: 'awaitable' has not been declared in 'boost::asio'
   22 | using boost::asio::awaitable;
```

Comment: Unrelated: Don't use `-lpthread`, [use `-pthread`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23250863/difference-between-pthread-and-lpthread-while-compiling).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, coroutines are not enabled by default in gcc. You need to pass the `-fcoroutines` compiler switch in order to enable them. This will probably change soon as it already works with the current gcc trunk version.

See [here](https://godbolt.org/z/haYW9T) (I had to comment out the code in main due to the execution time cap in godbolt.org).