# pthread_yield problem compiling 32 bit program

Tags: ubuntu, gcc, pthreads

I'm facing an issue that I'm not sure why is happening or how to solve it:
My problem is that I'm trying to compile inferno-os (A distributed OS) on a Virtual Machine, I've had some issues on the process like some libraries not being installed or GCC not being able to perform certain tasks (Inferno-OS is not particularly new), but I've found a way of solving that, all that is mainly because a part of the software is meant to run only on 32-bit mode only ([You can check it here](https://inferno-os.org/inferno/downloads.html)), and since I'm using a 64-bit VM (Xubuntu22.04), I did that. Anyway, now, I'm facing an error because of `pthread_yield` function, basically, it said undefined reference when I was building the OS, so I decided to try the example I found [here](https://www.thegeekdiary.com/pthread_yield-example-in-c/) and it stills give me the undefined reference problem.

I have a file named thread.c where I've got the example I found, and I've tried to get the binary from it with:

```bash
cc -m32 thread.c -lpthread
```

```bash
cc -m32 -pthread thread.c
```

and

```bash
cc -m32 thread.c -lthread
```

but all of those give me the same message "undefined reference to `pthread_yield`"

Here is a picture of the command that inferno's installation process executes, note that it's in Spanish but the output says basically undefined reference to `pthread_yield` [[image: Inferno run]]

I would really appreciate some help here, I would really like to know why is this happening

Comment: I'm uncertain whether it would resolve your issue, but the compile command presented shows explicitly linking against libpthread and *not* using the `-pthread` option, which is contrary to the docs.  With GCC, compilation of a pthreads-based program should do the opposite: use `-pthread` (not `-lpthread`), for both compiling and linking, and omit `-lpthread`.

Comment: Note also that `pthread_yield()` was never standard and is now deprecated by glibc (the standard alternative is `sched_yield()`).  Perhaps that's a factor.

Comment: Thanks man, as I said before, I also tried compiling a program using the `-pthread` flag but it makes no difference, there is more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23250863/difference-between-pthread-and-lpthread-while-compiling) if you want to go and check it out. Anyways I think I assumed the `pthread_yield` function was included with the glibc and now I realize It isn't, thanks for the advice :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't ignore compiler warnings, especially those about implicit function declarations.  The warning tells you that `pthread_yield` is an undeclared function.  Either build with `-D_GNU_SOURCE` to get a declaration of `pthread_yield`, or include `<sched.h>` and change `pthread_yield` to the standard `sched_yield` function.

Comment: The post describes an "undefined reference" link error, not a warning about calling an implicitly declared function.  And GCC will define `_GNU_SOURCE` automatically unless one of its strict(ish) standards modes, such as `-std=c17`, is turned on, which does not appear to be the case for the OP.

Comment: Current glibc provides a *definition* of `pthread_yield` only with `_GNU_SOURCE`, which leads to a compiler warning and a linker error if missing. The GNU C compiler does not default to `_GNU_SOURCE` in any mode, unlike the C++ compiler.

Comment: I can confirm that `-D_GNU_SOURCE` solved my issue! Thanks a lot!