# Calling an instance method only once

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, synchronization

I am trying to write a class which has a method that can only be called once per object (well, it can be called multiple times, but it will only do something the first time).

My example code is

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <mutex>
class OneCallClass
{
    private:
    std::once_flag f_once{};

    public:
    void f() 
    {
        std::call_once(f_once, 
            []() { std::cout << "First call\n"; }
        );
     }
};

int main()
{
    OneCallClass o;
    o.f();
    // o.f();
    // o.f();
}
```

and it [fails on Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/s69nonfc9) with the error message

```cpp
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::system_error'
  what():  Unknown error -1
Program terminated with signal: SIGSEGV
```

The code looks straight forward to me. I looked up [cppreference for `std::call_once()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/call_once) and I don't see how I'm doing it wrong.

Well, the documentation says

> std::system_error if any condition prevents calls to std::call_once from executing as specified

but which condition should that be?

I am creating an instance of the class on the stack. `f_once()` should be initialized due to `{}` and therefore I can use the rule of zero, no constructors, destuctors etc.

Where's the bug and how to fix it?

Comment: That's weird, it works for me when running the code in 2 online compilers and compiles fine in my own IDE using g++. Probably some library issues in the Godbolt site?

Comment: It works like a charm on Qt so Godbolt might be the issue. Adding a `static int` within `f()` as well as try catch around `std::call_once` and print i each time. Calling the 3 `o.f()` in main, only one call is done with i == 0.

Comment: Indeed, it works in Visual Studio as well. Maybe I should use a real IDE sometimes :-D

Comment: you need `-lpthread` : https://godbolt.org/z/fz9s3odbs

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai: thanks. How did you know?

Comment: just a guess. Doing stuff with threads requires `-lpthread` with gcc, if you dont, strange things can happen during runtime.

Comment: well, a lame answer is better than none. Such duplicates are notoriously hard to find, as the symptoms are various even though the fix is the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `-lpthread` when using facilities from the thread support library.

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/fz9s3odbs)

Comment: I believe `-pthread` should generally be used instead of `-lpthread`. See the following question for further information: [Difference between -pthread and -lpthread while compiling](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23250863/12149471)

Comment: @AndreasWenzel I admit its the first time I hear about this difference. I actually believe here `lphtread` is sufficient, because there is only a single thread in OPs code. I'll have to do more reading before I can fix the answer